# Noise reduction Filter for acceleration data

Tags: filter, accelerometer, imu

I have successfully compensated the gravity from the IMU I am using through the use of madgwick filter. However, the result of linear acceleration comes out rather noisy with a high spike in between readings. Is there any filter or method I can use to filter my linear acceleration so that can better make use of the data to obtain velocity and displacement ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways in order to denoise the acceleration data is Fast Fourier Transform(FFT) your dataset followed by some Power Spectral Analysis and finally perform Inverse FFT to get the denoised data. I suggest you look into that.